# Freeform entries show users submitted entry

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

How do I show a users submitted entry using Freeform entries? For example I need to show an immediate response to a users form submission on a return page. ie:

```
            {exp:freeform:entries
                form_name="apply"
                orderby="entry_date" 
                sort="desc"
                limit="1"
                status="pending" 
            }

               {if '{freeform:field:age-range}'=="Yes" AND '{freeform:field:health}'=="Yes"}Your'e OK{if:else} You're not OK{/if}<br />


            {/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your FreeForm form tag, you need to set your return parameter to include the entry_id that gets created when the form is submitted:

```
{exp:freeform:form return="form-success/%%entry_id%%" form_id="1"}
    Form stuff here!
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

And then on your success page, you just grab the entry_id from whatever segment it ends up as:

```
{exp:freeform:entries entry_id="{segment_2}" form_id="1"}
    Form output here!
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Comment: Additional reading if you're looking for some extra security on displaying Freeform entries (`{exp:freeform:edit}` and `{exp:freeform:entries}` would work similarly): http://support.solspace.com/solution/categories/115922/folders/4000005609/articles/4000032469-how-to-make-freeform-forms-editable-without-using-the-entry-id-in-the-url